# "Succeed in" or "succeed at"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are "He succeeded *in* business" and "He succeeded *at* business" both idiomatic? What is a good resource for learning idiomatic verb-preposition pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

When I tried to search for an answer to your question, I had many more hits for succeed *at* than succeed *in*, and no easy source wherein a grammatical comparison is made. *Succeed in* was often followed by a context (school, life), whereas succeed at was often followed by what might be considered a task (being yourself, work, divorce, psychometric testing.)

From this, I would guess both are common, and it might be up to your discretion which you use.

I do think they carry different connotations. (Please forgive the redundancy.) To *succeed in life* means something very different to me that to *succeed at life*. To me, *to succeed in* implies to do well within a context (life), whereas *to succeed at* implies doing well in conquering a task (life).

> To *succeed in* life, one must *succeed at* being oneself. (my nonsense, not the words of anyone else.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The distinction between context and task is good, and will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Both Cambridge and Oxford's dictionaries show succeed being followed by the prepostion "in".
On Cambridge English tests (FCE, CAE and CPE) the combination "to succeed at" is considered an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used 'succeeding' in followed by a gerund.

He succeeded in duping his clients for many years.

I wouldn't use 'at' in this context ever.

Further to that I agree with the post above and the suggested connotations of 'in' concerning doing well within a context and 'at' concerning doing well at conquering a task.