# Succeed at vs succeed in [American English]

Tags: prepositions, american-english

There is a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140976/succeed-in-or-succeed-at) but it’s not completely answered.
For example, [Ludwig shows](https://ludwig.guru/s/succeed+at) that The New York Times and others use both. Merriam-Webster also [contains both](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=en-us&sxsrf=ALeKk02E6Zq9cl0nzGEwheBmRZFk4-Jo6Q%3A1593735067521&ei=m3f-XoO8H7esytMP6qyAqAI&q=%22succeed+at%22+site%3Awww.merriam-webster.com&oq=%22succeed+at%22+site%3Awww.merriam-webster.com&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1CPf1jjkwFgg5cBaABwAXgAgAE3iAFtkgEBMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjD9cLk5a_qAhU3lnIEHWoWACUQ4dUDCAs&uact=5). Is it a difference between AE and BE? Are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: They would tend to be used in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

*Succeed **in*** seems by far the more common in both AmE and BrE.

Some stats from the British National Corpus and the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

[image: succeed PREP]

[image]

When followed by a gerund-participial, COCA has both, but the BNC returns no results:

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

This suggests that *at* may be less acceptable when there is a gerund-participial complement in BrE.

When followed by a noun phrase, the balance still tilts heavily in favor of *in* for both the BNC and COCA, however it's dubious whether these prepositional phrases are really complements of *succeed* as they often denote domains or physical locations more so than actions.